# how to access textbox from within class file

Tags: c#, class, textbox

In C# i would like to access textbox from page directly without sending it as variable to the class for example

#### file class.cs code

```
public class A {
    private string dosomething {
        string text;
        text = textbox1.text; 
        // textbox1 exists in, for example, default.aspx, and I need it's 
        // value in the class after some event occurred - let's say there 
        // is button and it was clicked 
    return text;
    }
}
```

#### default.aspx.cs code

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    A a = new A(); 
    // I need when this button clicked to fill the variable within
    // the class with the data given from the textbox within this page
}
```

This is what I've come up with, but I'm not sure if I'm taking the right path using a getter and setter this way:

```
private TextBox TextBox1 = new TextBox();
public string  settext {
    get { return TextBox1.Text; }
    set { TextBox1.Text = value;}
}
```

but I always get a `NullReferenceException was unhandled` message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found what i'm looking for and it's working like charm i will put the way i did and the link for the article helped me to figure out how to solve it
http://codebetter.com/jefferypalermo/2004/09/01/asp-net-2-0-master-pages-changes-the-pages-control-hierarchy-level-300/
in case using master page same idea for without master page in my case i was using master page and i tested it on both with and without working fine

```
    private TextBox  gettextbox ( )
    {

        //without master page
           /*System.Web.UI.Page Default = (System.Web.UI.Page)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Handler;
             TextBox TextBox1 = (TextBox)Default[0].FindControl("TextBox1");*/

        //with master page
       System.Web.UI.Page Default = (System.Web.UI.Page)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Handler;
   ContentPlaceHolder cph = Default.Controls[0].FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1") as ContentPlaceHolder;
           TextBox Textbox1 = (TextBox)cph.FindControl("TextBox1");
           return Textbox1;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Add it to the constructor

```
A a = new A(this.TextBox1.Text);

public class A
{
    private String _Text;

    public A(String text){

       this._Text = text;
    }

}
```

The private _Text variable can be accessed internally by the class only, however if you change to a `public` property you can access it after creating an instance

```
A a = new A(this.TextBox1.Text);
String text = a._Text;
```

Further to this, if it was a public variable then you can just create the instance and set the _Text and would not need the `public A(String text)` constructor:

```
A a = new A();
a._Text = this.TextBox1.Text;
String seeIfSet = a._Text;
```

Comment: Also known as "Dependency Injection" - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa973811.aspx.

Comment: Thakns it's working but not what i'm looking for , what i'm looking for as i said i need it directly in the class cause i have 10 text boxes in default.aspx and need all of they values into variables in the class and i need just to to keep all the dirty work within the class just need to initiate the class / make the instance and leave all the dirty work with in the class file sorry it was my mistake not clearing what i need in the first place